# Building a docker image on EC2 for web application with many dependencies

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I am very new to Docker and have some very basic questions. I was unable to get my doubts clarified elsewhere and hence posting it here. Pardon me if the queries are very obvious. I know I lack some basic understanding regarding images but i had a hard time finding some easy to understand explanation for the whole of it.

**Problem at hand:**

I have my application running on an EC2 node (r4.xlarge). It is a web application which has a LOT of dependencies (system dependencies + other libraries etc). I would like to create a docker image of my machine so that i can easily run it at ease when I launch a new EC2 instance.

**Questions:**

1. Do i need to build the docker image from scratch or can I use some base image?
2. If i can use a base image, which one do I select? (It is hard to know the OS version on the EC2 machine and hence I am not sure which base image do i start on.
   I referred this documentation- 
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html#install_docker
   But it creates from an Ubuntu base image.
3. The above example has instructions on installing apache (and other things needed for the application). Let's say my application needs server X to be installed + 20 system dependencies + 10 other libraries.

Ex:

```
    yum install gcc
    yum install gfortran
    wget <abc>
```

When I create a docker file do i need to specify all the installation instructions like above? I thought creating an image is like taking a copy of your existing machine. What is the docker file supposed to have in this case?

Pointing me out to some good documentation to build a docker image on EC2 for a web app with dependencies will be very useful too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you want to move toward docker then I will suggest using AWS ECS which specially designed for docker container and have auto-scaling and load balancing feature.

As for your question is concern so

1. You need a docker file which contains all the packages and application which already installed in your EC2 instance. As for base image is concern i will recommend **Alpine**. Docker default image is **Alpine**

**Why Alpine?**
*Alpine describes itself as:*

> Small. Simple. Secure. Alpine Linux is a security-oriented,
>   lightweight Linux distribution based on musl libc and busybox.

https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/the-3-biggest-wins-when-using-alpine-as-a-base-docker-image

https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/

> Let's say my application needs server X to be installed + 20 system
>   dependencies + 10 other libraries.

So You need to make dockerfile which need all these you mentioned.

**Again I will suggest ECS for best docker based application because that is ECS that designed for docker, not EC2**.

> CONTAINERIZE EVERYTHING
>
> Amazon ECS lets you easily build all types of
>   containerized applications, from long-running applications and
>   microservices to batch jobs and machine learning applications. You can
>   migrate legacy Linux or Windows applications from on-premises to the
>   cloud and run them as containerized applications using Amazon ECS.

https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/deploy-docker-containers/

https://caylent.com/containers-kubernetes-docker-swarm-amazon-ecs/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will go through ECS and see if it is a good fit.

Comment: If there is any issue regarding ECS ECR , Task definition load balancing auto-scaling feel free to ask and accept the answer if it will lead to solving the problem.

Comment: I need to run just one container application on a docker. Scaling it is not a requirement as of now, the complexity is only in case of building and handling system dependencies. I see that ECS has 2 models - fargate and ec2 type model. I feel the ec2 type model suffices in my case. What do you think?

Comment: fargate is currently expensive as compared to ec2 type ,fargate is like lambda they charege you for requests. Yeah ec2 type is suffices and it will be work in future for scaling and balancing.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use a base image, you specify it with the first line of
   your Docker file, with `FROM`
2. The base OS of the EC2 instance doesn't matter for the container.
   that's the point of containers, you can run linux on windows, arch
   on debian, whatever you want.
3. Yes, dependencies that don't exist in your base image will need to
   be specified and installed. ( Depending on the default packager
   manger for the base image you are working from you might use dpkg,
   or yum or apt-get. )